# SHA256 implementation in c

Tags: c, sha256

I am trying to program SHA256 implementation from this website: http://bradconte.com/sha256_c
in a MSP430 MCU board. I am using the open-source Energia IDE for programming.

This is the testcode:

```
 unsigned char  hash[32];
 SHA256_CTX ctx;
 sha256_init(&ctx);
 sha256_update(&ctx,(unsigned char*)"abc",3);
 sha256_final(&ctx,hash);
 PrintHex(hash);
```

This converts to hex

```
 void PrintHex(unsigned char * data) 
 {
    char tmp[16];
    for (int i=0; i<32; i++) { 
    sprintf(tmp, "%02x",data[i]); 
    Serial.print(tmp); 
    }
 }
```

The problem is that the output is always a wrong hash code.

This is the output:

```
    2bb53935edbba17dc04a04854518754d8a66484491b585b0d0700cd2512f5420
```

Is it the testcode or something else that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: this is expected: `ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad` for the abc characters

Comment: Can you test your code on your desktop using a normal compiler to see if that works?

Comment: it works in a normal compiler. So the problem is probably that the code is not working correctly in IDE?

Comment: I'd tried to use this code on a 16 bit bare metal platform (St10) and run into exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran that code on my system (Mac OS X, x86 64-bit) and it gave me this:

```
551ce4769446b343295ea7f819ba1c5557545e29a4de545746b2b246a9831f22
```

I think we can safely assume the code is crap: I verified that ba7816b... is the correct hash using some online tools, and now we see that your platform and mine both produce different results.  I noticed some comment in the code about endianness so I looked it up and your system is also little-endian, so that shouldn't be a problem.  I'd advise you to look for a different implementation.

Comment: Not so fast, the problem is that he assumes that an ulong has exactly 32 bits - that may make sense on an embedded system, but it fails on most computers; fixing it gives me the correct result. Re the endianness: does it say anywhere what platform he's assuming?

Comment: @pattex007 in case the code does turn out to be unusable, the skalibs have an implementation which claims to be endianness independent, and the author cares a lot about getting his code to run on embedded systems.

Comment: how do I get digest out of "hash" variable?

Comment: I just built this code on MacOS 10.11.3 and I got the expected result, so unfortunately for you, I'll be downvoting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not assume the string encoding to be portable in C.

Try this code instead:

```
unsigned char message[] = {0x61, 0x62, 0x63};
unsigned char hash[32];
SHA256_CTX ctx;
sha256_init(&ctx);
sha256_update(&ctx,message,sizeof message);
sha256_final(&ctx,hash);
PrintHex(hash);
```

Answer (score 1):

I mean that original site was no longer valid, but I think that I have same implementation and I had same problem on MSP430. Question was aksed long time ago, but still someone may be in similar trouble.

```
/*********************************************************************
* Filename:   sha256.c
* Author:     Brad Conte (brad AT bradconte.com)
```

Therefore some additional changes must be made in original implementation, to properly calculate SHA256 sum on MSP430. It may depend on compiler - currently I used one from Texas CCStudio, and this is not definitely not GNU GCC.

First, **sha256.h** file should be changed similar to this:

```
...
/*************************** HEADER FILES ***************************/
#include <stdint.h>

/****************************** MACROS ******************************/
#define SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE 32            // SHA256 outputs a 32 byte digest

/**************************** DATA TYPES ****************************/
typedef uint8_t   BYTE;             // 8-bit byte
typedef uint32_t  WORD;             // 32-bit word, change to "long" for 16-bit machines

typedef struct {
    BYTE     data[64];
    WORD     datalen;
    uint64_t bitlen;
    WORD     state[8];
} SHA256_CTX;

...
```

On 16-bit machines *unsigned int* is a 16-bit integer without sign. So replace *WORD* typedef to appropiate type. I think this was bad, to use own *WORD* and *BYTE* definitions, where they are available in **stdint.h** header file.

For second, I think that implementation of *sha256_transform* was badly coded. There are bitwise operations on *BYTE*, that gives out of scale results.

After adding explicit conversions on *BYTE* before doing bitwise operations, all implementation become working well on MSP430 MCU. Just see below code:

```
/*********************** FUNCTION DEFINITIONS ***********************/
void sha256_transform ( SHA256_CTX *ctx, const BYTE data[] )
{
    WORD a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, t1, t2, m[64];

    for ( i = 0, j = 0; i < 16; ++i, j += 4)
        /* Add explicit (WORD) conversion before operating on bytes */
        m[i] = ((WORD)data[j] << 24) | ((WORD)data[j + 1] << 16) | ((WORD)data[j + 2] << 8) | ((WORD)data[j + 3]);
    for ( ; i < 64; ++i)
        m[i] = SIG1(m[i - 2]) + m[i - 7] + SIG0(m[i - 15]) + m[i - 16];

    a = ctx->state[0];
    b = ctx->state[1];
```

I hope, that this help someone to solve the problem.